# How to gain access to gpiochipX

Tags: android, linux-kernel, embedded, gpio, sysfs

We are programming on an Android-based microcontroller and we want to be able to access the gpio pins on the board. Looking through the documentation, the 12 gpio pins we want to use are various pins between # 0-100, however, there are no gpiochips available for it. For instance, gpiochip576 is available, but we do not have need for gpios 576+ and above. We want to gain access to 0-100. Is there an easy way to gain access to them? We found this article: http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/15 ,that if we are right, seems to gain access to a gpiochip, but requires a lot of c code, and in our case since its android, we need to recompile the kernel and system image and flash it onto the board. Is there an easier way maybe via sysfs(something like echo "14" > /sys/class/gpio/export) or something else so we gain access? Or is our only option modifying the kernel and recompiling. Thank you!

Comment: You say there are GPIO pins available but not the numbers you look for. Have you looked into Linux documentation for your controller for pin number mapping? Unfortunately the numbers LInux drivers use and the numbers in the controller's datasheet may not be identical.

Comment: What is your board (or at least, what is your SoC)? What is the kernel version you are using (and where you obtained it from)? Is it using device tree or board file? Either way, can you see gpio chip device definition in your device tree/board file? Can you see also your gpio chip driver being loaded correctly? If everything in place -- check out [Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt): you should be able to export your GPIO pin via sysfs and then use it (via files under corresponding directory that will appear).

Comment: @AndreasBombe Yes, for instance physical gpio 21 on the board corresponds to gpio 86 or something via sysfs interface. The problem is, before we can actually use gpio 86, we need a gpiochip that gives us access(for instance maybe gpiochip72 with gpion = 36. these are random numbers I am using). We have the physical gpio mappings to the virtual ones, but we have no way to access the virtual ones via sysfs. Is there a way we can turn it on?

Comment: @SamProtsenko For what is the SoC, is "Expansion Header" an acceptable answer? The kernel seems to be "LK" or Little Kerner, which is based off the android bootloader, and it seems to be using a device tree as well. I personally have not ever had this problem on previous microcontrollers(raspberry pi and ifc6410 all had the necessary gpiochips readily available), so I am a little unsure on where to start.
Currently, via sysfs, gpiochip576, gpiochip608, ... etc. are all loaded, but we need gpiochip0, gpiochip32, and thus we cannot gain access to the gpio pins that we need.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Do you have any resources that you would recommend that I can read, or tell me where to start to solve this issue? And also, since this is an android based os, would we need to keep recompiling the os image and reflashing the board with it? If I am correct, on Linux, we just need to recompile the necessary files.

Comment: @user3855005 For SoC I mean [System on chip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip). For kernel version -- I mean Linux kernel version (like 3.0 or 3.14 etc). You should start from checking if you have driver for your GPIO IP-core (on your SoC) loaded in Linux kernel. For this you need to know what is your SoC model exactly. Next you need to check your device tree `dts` file for your board. For this you need to know your board model. Once GPIO chip driver loaded and device tree has correct definition -- GPIo capabilities (like export) should work fine in sysfs.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Oh i understand now. The soc is the Snapdragon 410 MSM8916. At the moment, I cannot check the linux kernel, but I will let you know asap. So just in general, I need to download the kernel code, modify this dts file, recompile the kernel and flash onto the microcontroller? And for modifying the dts file, I am assuming I would use something like this?: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-msm.txt

Comment: @user3855005 Yes, you need to check your kernel. First of all, you need to find out which driver is used for your GPIO controller. You should look into your defconfig file for your board (`arch/arm/configs/...`). Also check it in your device tree files (`.dts`, `.dtsi`) -- you should find name of your GPIO controller. After this you should check in `dmesg` that driver for GPIO controller was loaded correctly (w/o errors). Then check pin muxes in device tree. If everything in place -- you should be able to use sysfs interface for GPIO.

Comment: @user3855005 Also you should check how gpio numbers in sysfs are mapped to actual gpio pins. There can be some mess. Again, check it in your device tree file and maybe in your GPIO controller driver code. To tell more than that I need to have TRM for your SoC, schematic for your board and sources. Which I presume can't be done :)

Comment: @SamProtsenko Yeah, at the moment we have no schematics nor TRM for the snapdragon. With regards to the mappings, we do have that, so that shouldnt be the problem(that's how I found out we were missing the specific gpio controllers). As soon as I get access to the kernel and I try out what you said, I will let you know. Thank you so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update for any future users having problems with this same issue:

We were looking for gpios 0-120 and assumed that we needed gpio0 with a gpion=120, but in actuality, there was an offset applied, meaning that the gpios were found in the 576+ range. Just needed to add a constant number to each of the pins.

Just as SamProtsenko described in the comments with the questions, any modifications needed will need to be done in the device tree files, and then recompiled and uploaded to your device. SamProtsenko does a good job explaining what is needed to be done, so please check the comments above. Otherwise, you will need to learn more about how the device tree works.